# Mutually exclusive attributes using Flow

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, flowtype, typechecking

I'm building a UI component in the company I work for. It's in React Native and it uses Flow to typecheck. Thing is I want the components to have certain variants but they force me to have nothing but `booleans` for components attributes. And I'd like the components to disallow the use of more than one variant.

Let's say my component `<Button>` has two variants: `primary` and `secondary`. If I could use an attribute `variant` it would be easier because I would be able to use `variant='primary'`. But I can't do that. It has to be `primary=true` but I have to make it exclusive: if I have `primary:true` you shouldn't be allowed to use `secondary:true` in the same component.

I'been checking the [docs](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/unions/) but I couldn't find a way. And it makes sense, why would you have one? Just stop using `boolean`'s for everything, right?

Question is: Is there a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I follow all the magic you're trying to implement, but this one:

> if I have *primary:true* you shouldn't be allowed to use *secondary:true* in the same component.

Is quite easy to achieve with [exact object types](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/#toc-exact-object-types). Just create 2 different exact object types and mark component props as one of those:

```
type TPrimary = {|
  primary: boolean,
|};

type TSecondary = {|
  secondary: boolean,
|};

type T = TPrimary | TSecondary;

const C = (props: T) => <div {...props} />

const mounted = <C primary  />;

const mounted2 = <C secondary  />;

// error
const mounted3 = <C primary secondary  />
```

[Try](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoAlgWwA5wE4AuyYAhgM5gBKApiQMZFR5yZgDketDbA3KqgQCe2amAAqABTxYSeQWAC8YAN4AfVGDDZpmWYIBcYAEZw4MWgDsANKlUBfPgOGixAZWp04FgCZ7FK9U0yDy9fOUMTM0sbe0chEXF-SR0-VXF3Tx89R0yyIgBhfwAKbThsMkMxAEpFAD4wAB5vdAA3FQA6TtLyuzBgWv5cokw4AFcLAmpvfwbC7Rk5TX6+TVQhsBHxye8AJhnC4Myw+T7ax2BgMGo8Zjw1rzyNsYmpgGZ9rRTFw9C-U6A)

Comment: Thank you! I think this worked. But it's not triggering errors when the component is used on other files/